# Cannot impilicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'

Tags: c#

I've been struggling a lot because of this error - Cannot implicitly convert type `void` to `string`.

I cannot find a solution for mine so I will just ask. 
I'm making an auto-updater and I thought that not every update will be needed for the software, so I made a thing called:

```
string UpdateRequired = WebClient.DownloadString("url");
```

I just simply download a string to check if the update is required then if it's not required it's not doing anything if it is required I made this:

```
string File = "file url";
string mainpath = Application.StartupPath;
string DownloadFile = Address.DownloadFile(File, mainpath);
```

And then it's throwing an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'

If anybody knows how to fix it I would very appreciate this.

Comment: Does `Address.DownloadFile` return a value?

Comment: I dont think so.

Comment: Well, there's your answer then.

Comment: Well, there's your problem. If `Address.DownloadFile` doesn't return a value, then you can't assign that value to the string variable `DownloadFile`

Comment: So, how do I do that?

Comment: Is the second parameter of `DownloadFile` (aka `mainpath`) specified as an `out` parameter? If it is then the `string` you are looking for is most likely in there.

Comment: Your question is a bit misleading. It is not like you have a void pointer and cast it to some type. You are trying to get something were there isn't anything to get. Maybe in the quantum universe you can do it.

Comment: Post your `Address.DownloadFile` code.

Answer (score 4):

If your method doesn't return anything, you can't assign it to variable.  Remove the assignemnt.

```
string File = "file url";
string mainpath = Application.StartupPath;
Address.DownloadFile(File, mainpath);
```